# Create a function to test a value between two ranges

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a function within this code to kick the user back if the input values are outside of the input ranges, so if the first number with the second number doesn't exceed the high range or fall below the low rang with any of the calculations, if it does it would return with an error message and prompt to try again.

```
while True:
    try:
        number1 = int(input('Enter your Lower Range:'))
        if number1 < -100 or number1 > 100:
            raise ValueError 
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid integer. The number must be between -100 and 100.")

while True:
    try:
        number2 = int(input('Enter your Higher Range: '))
        if number2  < -100 or number2 > 100:
            raise ValueError 
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid integer. The number must be between -100 and 100.")

while True:
    try:
        a = int(input('Enter your first number: '))
        if a < -100 or a > 100:
            raise ValueError 
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid integer. The number must be between -100 and 100.")

while True:
    try:
        b = int(input('Enter your second number: '))
        if b < -100 or b > 100:
            raise ValueError 
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid integer. The number must be between -100 and 100.")

print('{} + {} = '.format(a, b))
print(a + b)

print('{} - {} = '.format(a, b))
print(a - b)

print('{} * {} = '.format(a, b))
print(a * b)

print('{} / {} = '.format(a, b))
print(a / b)

restart = input("Would you like to restart this program?")
if restart == "yes" or restart == "y":
        main()
if restart == "n" or restart == "no":
        print ("Script terminating. Goodbye.")
print ("Thanks for using my calculator!")
```

main()

Comment: Looks like each input for which you're prompting the user already has a mechanism for indefinitely repeating the question until satisfied (i.e. until a `ValueError` is not raised). Can't you just extend that? i.e. raise a `ValueError` when the `a` or `b` value doesn't satisfy the range criterion?  It's unclear where your roadblock might be. stackoverflow can help better if you show what you've already tried in solving your problem, and highlight where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this into a method, you can try the following:

```py
def read_number(text, lower=-100, higher=100):
    while True:
        number = int(input(text))
        if number < lower or number > higher:
            print("Invalid integer. The number must be between {} and {}.".format(lower, higher)
            pass
        else:
            return number
```

The method `read_number()` above get the input and returns it only on condition, so you can use it directly to a variable:

```py
def main():
    number1 = read_number('Enter your Lower Range: ')
    number2 = read_number('Enter your Higher Range: ')
    a = read_number('Enter your first number: ')
    b = read_number('Enter your second number: ')

    # do something ...
```

I don't know if is it you want. If not, try to explain it with more clarity.

However, I hope has helped you.

Comment: Thanks, your input really helped me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried my best to design a function. I hope this helps:

```
def my_calculator():
    while True:
        try:
            number1 = int(input('Enter your Lower Range:'))
            if number1 < -100 or number1 > 100:
                raise ValueError
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid integer. The number must be between -100 and 100.")

    while True:
        try:
            number2 = int(input('Enter your Higher Range: '))
            if number2 < -100 or number2 > 100:
                raise ValueError
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid integer. The number must be between -100 and 100.")

    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input('Enter your first number: '))
            if a < -100 or a > 100:
                raise ValueError
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid integer. The number must be between -100 and 100.")

    while True:
        try:
            b = int(input('Enter your second number: '))
            if b < -100 or b > 100:
                raise ValueError
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid integer. The number must be between -100 and 100.")

    print('{} + {} = '.format(a, b))
    addition = a + b
    print(addition)

    print('{} - {} = '.format(a, b))
    diff = a - b
    print(diff)

    print('{} * {} = '.format(a, b))
    prod = a * b
    print(prod)

    quo = None
    try:
        quo = a / b
    except ZeroDivisionError as ze:
        print("Division by zero not allowed; Please retry.")
        my_calculator()

    print('{} / {} = '.format(a, b))
    print(quo) if quo else print()

    results = [addition, diff, prod, quo]
    try:
        if not all(-100 < i < 100 for i in results):
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError as ve:
        print("Some of the results of calculation exceed 100 or are less than -100."
              "The results must be between -100 and 100. Please retry.")
        my_calculator()

    restart = input("Would you like to restart this program?")
    if restart == "yes" or restart == "y":
        my_calculator()
    if restart == "n" or restart == "no":
        print("Script terminating. Goodbye.")
    print("Thanks for using my calculator!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_calculator()
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!